# Получение списка друзей в Twitter

Tags: twitter, twitter-api

Нужно получить список друзей в твиттере.

Авторизацию я выполнил, токены получил.

В официально документации https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/friends/list указаны только основные параметры запроса. Как туда приклеить токены, я не знаю :(

Comment: Точно также, как при авторизации в заголовке, типа: "Authorization: Bearer/Basic token".

Comment: @alexis031182 т.е. мне просто добавить 1 заголовок с oauth_token?

Comment: @alexis031182 я делал авторизация в твиттере со входом. Т.е. в результате у меня есть 2 токена: oauth_token и oauth_token_secret.

Comment: Я этот вариант авторизации не делал, мне был достаточен токен только приложения, но если предполагать аналогичность, то нужно далее в запросы добавлять заголовок: "Authorization: OAuth oauth_token". Соответственно вместо "oauth_token" подставляйте свой ключ. Также, возможно, имеет смысл попробовать и "oauth_token_secret" добавить через запятую. В справке твиттера, что-то не богато эта тема раскрыта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я разобрался. Способ подписи к запросам настолько же долбанутый, что и авторизация с входом.

1. Нужно сгенерировать oauth_signature по следующим параметрам

   - oauth_consumer_key
   - oauth_token
   - oauth_nonce
   - oauth_timestamp
   - oauth_signature_method
   - oauth_version
   - +все параметры вашего запроса
2. Далее подготавливаем тело заголовка

`<тело> = "oauth_nonce=" + oauth_nonce + "," +`

`"oauth_signature_method=" + oauth_signature_method + "," +`

`"oauth_token=" + urlencode(oauth_token) + "," +`

`"oauth_timestamp=" + oauth_timestamp + "," +`

`"oauth_consumer_key=" + oauth_consumer_key + "," +`

`"oauth_signature=" + urlencode(oauth_signature) + "," +`

`"oauth_version=" + oauth_version`

Внимание! Это вроде как не обязательно, но я каждое значение обрамлял кавычками.

3. Добавляем заголовок "Authorization : <тело>" и отправляем запрос

Если есть вопросы - задавайте

`

Comment: Странно, что всю эту ботву с ключами надо отправлять с каждым запросом. По идее, там же на последнем шаге два ключа только остаются. С ними не идут запросы, если сформировать заголовок по тому же принципу, что описали в ответе?

Comment: @alexis031182 я нашел 2 сайта, в котором именно так и делалось http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12684765/twitter-api-returns-error-215-bad-authentication-data http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=2021

Comment: Ну вот например [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16578726) используется всего 4 ключа: 2 ключа приложения и 2 ключа пользователя. Что там внутри этого вызываемого класса, надо разбираться и смотреть, но по идее так и должно быть. А иначе получается какой-то совсем перебор с телом заголовка авторизации. Впрочем, может ошибаюсь.

Comment: @alexis031182 нууу, твиттер по крайней мере обрабатывает мой запрос :D

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests) официальная документация по создании авторизированных запросов